# Converting array to align equations automatically

Tags: equations, align

I have an ugly and ginormous matrix and I need to automatically put them in an aligned equation form. Each cell should be put in an equation. For the cell in the first row and second column, it should be `$r_{12} &= c_{\theta_1}$`. The matrix is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
$$
\left(\begin{array}{ccccccc} 0 & c_{\theta_1} & s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_2} & c_{\theta_1}\,c_{\theta_3}-c_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_3} & s_{\theta_4}\,\left(c_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_3}+c_{\theta_2}\,c_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_1}\right)+c_{\theta_4}\,s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_2} & c_{\theta_5}\,\left(c_{\theta_1}\,c_{\theta_3}-c_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_3}\right)-s_{\theta_5}\,\left(c_{\theta_4}\,\left(c_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_3}+c_{\theta_2}\,c_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_1}\right)-s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_4}\right) & s_{\theta_6}\,\left(s_{\theta_5}\,\left(c_{\theta_1}\,c_{\theta_3}-c_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_3}\right)+c_{\theta_5}\,\left(c_{\theta_4}\,\left(c_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_3}+c_{\theta_2}\,c_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_1}\right)-s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_4}\right)\right)+c_{\theta_6}\,\left(s_{\theta_4}\,\left(c_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_3}+c_{\theta_2}\,c_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_1}\right)+c_{\theta_4}\,s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_2}\right)\\ 0 & s_{\theta_1} & -c_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_2} & c_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_1}+c_{\theta_1}\,c_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_3} & s_{\theta_4}\,\left(s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_3}-c_{\theta_1}\,c_{\theta_2}\,c_{\theta_3}\right)-c_{\theta_1}\,c_{\theta_4}\,s_{\theta_2} & c_{\theta_5}\,\left(c_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_1}+c_{\theta_1}\,c_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_3}\right)-s_{\theta_5}\,\left(c_{\theta_4}\,\left(s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_3}-c_{\theta_1}\,c_{\theta_2}\,c_{\theta_3}\right)+c_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_4}\right) & s_{\theta_6}\,\left(s_{\theta_5}\,\left(c_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_1}+c_{\theta_1}\,c_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_3}\right)+c_{\theta_5}\,\left(c_{\theta_4}\,\left(s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_3}-c_{\theta_1}\,c_{\theta_2}\,c_{\theta_3}\right)+c_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_4}\right)\right)+c_{\theta_6}\,\left(s_{\theta_4}\,\left(s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_3}-c_{\theta_1}\,c_{\theta_2}\,c_{\theta_3}\right)-c_{\theta_1}\,c_{\theta_4}\,s_{\theta_2}\right)\\ 1 & 0 & c_{\theta_2} & s_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_3} & c_{\theta_2}\,c_{\theta_4}-c_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_4} & s_{\theta_5}\,\left(c_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_4}+c_{\theta_3}\,c_{\theta_4}\,s_{\theta_2}\right)+c_{\theta_5}\,s_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_3} & c_{\theta_6}\,\left(c_{\theta_2}\,c_{\theta_4}-c_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_4}\right)-s_{\theta_6}\,\left(c_{\theta_5}\,\left(c_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_4}+c_{\theta_3}\,c_{\theta_4}\,s_{\theta_2}\right)-s_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_5}\right)\\ 0 & -\frac{17\,s_{\theta_1}}{50} & \frac{17\,c_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_2}}{50} & -\frac{2\,c_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_3}}{5}-\frac{17\,c_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_1}}{50}-\frac{17\,c_{\theta_1}\,c_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_3}}{50}-\frac{2\,c_{\theta_2}\,c_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_1}}{5} & \frac{17\,c_{\theta_1}\,c_{\theta_4}\,s_{\theta_2}}{50}+\frac{2\,c_{\theta_1}\,c_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_4}}{5}-\frac{17\,s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_4}}{50}+\frac{17\,c_{\theta_1}\,c_{\theta_2}\,c_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_4}}{50}-\frac{2\,c_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_4}}{5} & \left(c_{\theta_5}\,\left(c_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_1}+c_{\theta_1}\,c_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_3}\right)-s_{\theta_5}\,\left(c_{\theta_4}\,\left(s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_3}-c_{\theta_1}\,c_{\theta_2}\,c_{\theta_3}\right)+c_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_4}\right)\right)\,\left(\frac{17\,c_{\theta_2}}{50}+c_{\theta_2}\,\left(\frac{37\,c_{\theta_4}}{50}-\frac{37}{50}\right)-\frac{37\,c_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_4}}{50}-\frac{17}{50}\right)-\frac{57\,s_{\theta_5}\,\left(c_{\theta_1}\,c_{\theta_3}-c_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_3}\right)}{50}-\frac{57\,c_{\theta_5}\,\left(c_{\theta_4}\,\left(c_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_3}+c_{\theta_2}\,c_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_1}\right)-s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_4}\right)}{50}+\left(s_{\theta_5}\,\left(c_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_4}+c_{\theta_3}\,c_{\theta_4}\,s_{\theta_2}\right)+c_{\theta_5}\,s_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_3}\right)\,\left(\frac{17\,c_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_2}}{50}-\frac{37\,s_{\theta_4}\,\left(s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_3}-c_{\theta_1}\,c_{\theta_2}\,c_{\theta_3}\right)}{50}+c_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_2}\,\left(\frac{37\,c_{\theta_4}}{50}-\frac{37}{50}\right)\right) & \left(s_{\theta_6}\,\left(s_{\theta_5}\,\left(c_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_1}+c_{\theta_1}\,c_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_3}\right)+c_{\theta_5}\,\left(c_{\theta_4}\,\left(s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_3}-c_{\theta_1}\,c_{\theta_2}\,c_{\theta_3}\right)+c_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_4}\right)\right)+c_{\theta_6}\,\left(s_{\theta_4}\,\left(s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_3}-c_{\theta_1}\,c_{\theta_2}\,c_{\theta_3}\right)-c_{\theta_1}\,c_{\theta_4}\,s_{\theta_2}\right)\right)\,\left(\frac{17\,c_{\theta_2}}{50}+c_{\theta_2}\,\left(\frac{37\,c_{\theta_4}}{50}-\frac{37}{50}\right)-\frac{57\,s_{\theta_6}\,\left(c_{\theta_5}\,\left(c_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_4}+c_{\theta_3}\,c_{\theta_4}\,s_{\theta_2}\right)-s_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_5}\right)}{50}+\left(c_{\theta_2}\,c_{\theta_4}-c_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_4}\right)\,\left(\frac{57\,c_{\theta_6}}{50}-\frac{57}{50}\right)-\frac{37\,c_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_4}}{50}-\frac{17}{50}\right)-\left(c_{\theta_6}\,\left(c_{\theta_2}\,c_{\theta_4}-c_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_4}\right)-s_{\theta_6}\,\left(c_{\theta_5}\,\left(c_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_4}+c_{\theta_3}\,c_{\theta_4}\,s_{\theta_2}\right)-s_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_5}\right)\right)\,\left(\left(s_{\theta_4}\,\left(s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_3}-c_{\theta_1}\,c_{\theta_2}\,c_{\theta_3}\right)-c_{\theta_1}\,c_{\theta_4}\,s_{\theta_2}\right)\,\left(\frac{57\,c_{\theta_6}}{50}-\frac{57}{50}\right)+\frac{37\,s_{\theta_4}\,\left(s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_3}-c_{\theta_1}\,c_{\theta_2}\,c_{\theta_3}\right)}{50}+\frac{57\,s_{\theta_6}\,\left(s_{\theta_5}\,\left(c_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_1}+c_{\theta_1}\,c_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_3}\right)+c_{\theta_5}\,\left(c_{\theta_4}\,\left(s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_3}-c_{\theta_1}\,c_{\theta_2}\,c_{\theta_3}\right)+c_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_4}\right)\right)}{50}-\frac{17\,c_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_2}}{50}-c_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_2}\,\left(\frac{37\,c_{\theta_4}}{50}-\frac{37}{50}\right)\right)\\ 0 & \frac{17\,c_{\theta_1}}{50} & \frac{17\,s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_2}}{50} & \frac{17\,c_{\theta_1}\,c_{\theta_3}}{50}-\frac{2\,s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_3}}{5}+\frac{2\,c_{\theta_1}\,c_{\theta_2}\,c_{\theta_3}}{5}-\frac{17\,c_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_3}}{50} & \frac{17\,c_{\theta_4}\,s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_2}}{50}+\frac{17\,c_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_4}}{50}+\frac{2\,c_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_4}}{5}+\frac{2\,c_{\theta_1}\,c_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_4}}{5}+\frac{17\,c_{\theta_2}\,c_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_4}}{50} & \left(s_{\theta_5}\,\left(c_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_4}+c_{\theta_3}\,c_{\theta_4}\,s_{\theta_2}\right)+c_{\theta_5}\,s_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_3}\right)\,\left(\frac{17\,s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_2}}{50}+\frac{37\,s_{\theta_4}\,\left(c_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_3}+c_{\theta_2}\,c_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_1}\right)}{50}+s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_2}\,\left(\frac{37\,c_{\theta_4}}{50}-\frac{37}{50}\right)\right)-\frac{57\,s_{\theta_5}\,\left(c_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_1}+c_{\theta_1}\,c_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_3}\right)}{50}-\frac{57\,c_{\theta_5}\,\left(c_{\theta_4}\,\left(s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_3}-c_{\theta_1}\,c_{\theta_2}\,c_{\theta_3}\right)+c_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_4}\right)}{50}-\left(c_{\theta_5}\,\left(c_{\theta_1}\,c_{\theta_3}-c_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_3}\right)-s_{\theta_5}\,\left(c_{\theta_4}\,\left(c_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_3}+c_{\theta_2}\,c_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_1}\right)-s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_4}\right)\right)\,\left(\frac{17\,c_{\theta_2}}{50}+c_{\theta_2}\,\left(\frac{37\,c_{\theta_4}}{50}-\frac{37}{50}\right)-\frac{37\,c_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_4}}{50}-\frac{17}{50}\right) & \left(c_{\theta_6}\,\left(c_{\theta_2}\,c_{\theta_4}-c_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_4}\right)-s_{\theta_6}\,\left(c_{\theta_5}\,\left(c_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_4}+c_{\theta_3}\,c_{\theta_4}\,s_{\theta_2}\right)-s_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_5}\right)\right)\,\left(\frac{17\,s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_2}}{50}+\frac{37\,s_{\theta_4}\,\left(c_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_3}+c_{\theta_2}\,c_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_1}\right)}{50}+\left(s_{\theta_4}\,\left(c_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_3}+c_{\theta_2}\,c_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_1}\right)+c_{\theta_4}\,s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_2}\right)\,\left(\frac{57\,c_{\theta_6}}{50}-\frac{57}{50}\right)+\frac{57\,s_{\theta_6}\,\left(s_{\theta_5}\,\left(c_{\theta_1}\,c_{\theta_3}-c_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_3}\right)+c_{\theta_5}\,\left(c_{\theta_4}\,\left(c_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_3}+c_{\theta_2}\,c_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_1}\right)-s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_4}\right)\right)}{50}+s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_2}\,\left(\frac{37\,c_{\theta_4}}{50}-\frac{37}{50}\right)\right)-\left(s_{\theta_6}\,\left(s_{\theta_5}\,\left(c_{\theta_1}\,c_{\theta_3}-c_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_3}\right)+c_{\theta_5}\,\left(c_{\theta_4}\,\left(c_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_3}+c_{\theta_2}\,c_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_1}\right)-s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_4}\right)\right)+c_{\theta_6}\,\left(s_{\theta_4}\,\left(c_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_3}+c_{\theta_2}\,c_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_1}\right)+c_{\theta_4}\,s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_2}\right)\right)\,\left(\frac{17\,c_{\theta_2}}{50}+c_{\theta_2}\,\left(\frac{37\,c_{\theta_4}}{50}-\frac{37}{50}\right)-\frac{57\,s_{\theta_6}\,\left(c_{\theta_5}\,\left(c_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_4}+c_{\theta_3}\,c_{\theta_4}\,s_{\theta_2}\right)-s_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_5}\right)}{50}+\left(c_{\theta_2}\,c_{\theta_4}-c_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_4}\right)\,\left(\frac{57\,c_{\theta_6}}{50}-\frac{57}{50}\right)-\frac{37\,c_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_4}}{50}-\frac{17}{50}\right)\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{2\,c_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_2}}{5} & \frac{2\,s_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_4}}{5} & \frac{57\,c_{\theta_5}\,\left(c_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_4}+c_{\theta_3}\,c_{\theta_4}\,s_{\theta_2}\right)}{50}-\left(c_{\theta_5}\,\left(c_{\theta_1}\,c_{\theta_3}-c_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_3}\right)-s_{\theta_5}\,\left(c_{\theta_4}\,\left(c_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_3}+c_{\theta_2}\,c_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_1}\right)-s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_4}\right)\right)\,\left(\frac{17\,c_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_2}}{50}-\frac{37\,s_{\theta_4}\,\left(s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_3}-c_{\theta_1}\,c_{\theta_2}\,c_{\theta_3}\right)}{50}+c_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_2}\,\left(\frac{37\,c_{\theta_4}}{50}-\frac{37}{50}\right)\right)-\left(c_{\theta_5}\,\left(c_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_1}+c_{\theta_1}\,c_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_3}\right)-s_{\theta_5}\,\left(c_{\theta_4}\,\left(s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_3}-c_{\theta_1}\,c_{\theta_2}\,c_{\theta_3}\right)+c_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_4}\right)\right)\,\left(\frac{17\,s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_2}}{50}+\frac{37\,s_{\theta_4}\,\left(c_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_3}+c_{\theta_2}\,c_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_1}\right)}{50}+s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_2}\,\left(\frac{37\,c_{\theta_4}}{50}-\frac{37}{50}\right)\right)-\frac{57\,s_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_5}}{50} & \frac{2\,c_{\theta_6}\,s_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_4}}{5}+\frac{2\,c_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_5}\,s_{\theta_6}}{5}+\frac{2\,c_{\theta_5}\,s_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_6}}{5}+\frac{2\,c_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_4}\,s_{\theta_5}\,s_{\theta_6}}{5}+\frac{2\,c_{\theta_3}\,c_{\theta_4}\,s_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_5}\,s_{\theta_6}}{5}+\frac{2\,c_{\theta_4}\,c_{\theta_5}\,s_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_6}}{5} \end{array}\right)
$$
\end{document}
```

Edit: as requested in the comment section, this will illustrate exactly what I'm looking for.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}  c_{\theta_1} & -s_{\theta_2} \\ c_{\theta_2} & -s_{\theta_1} \end{array}
\right)
\]

\begin{align*}
r_{11} &=  c_{\theta_1} \\
r_{12} &= -s_{\theta_2} \\
r_{21} &= c_{\theta_2} \\
r_{22} &= -s_{\theta_1}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Unrelated: You're using `amsmath` why aren't you using `pmatrix` here? then no need for `\left/right` or `array`. Additionally `$$...$$` should no be used in any LaTeX doc as it does not follow LaTeX configurations.

Comment: @daleif, nice comment, unfortunately, this is an automated format by Matlab.

Comment: So far, you've supplied a single `array` environment. What exactly do you mean by "each cell should be put in an equation"? Cell (1,1) contains `0`: what does it mean to put `0` in an equation? *Which* equation are we talking about?

Comment: Though a solution should be possible with Tex or Latex, it's probably better to extract the required text portion and run it through some scripting, like Perl or PHP.

Comment: @MS-SPO this will be my last shot. I can use the regular expression in Matlab but I'm asking if there is a possibility with latex.

Comment: @Mico as you can see from the matrix, it is impossible to put it in a single line. I need to take each element in the matrix and put it in an independent equation so that I can see the elements of the matrix clearly.

Comment: @CroCo it still is far from clear what you want the result to look like, do you just want a vertical list of equations r_ij=value from cell ij or do you want to keep the matrix layout but add r_ij= to each cell (which is how I understood it originally)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle please see the update.

Comment: thanks, I could answer but maybe I'll leave it to @egreg he needs the points

Comment: @CroCo, Latex or Mathlab may not be your best choices for a task like this. BTW, Perl provides more nice things besides extracting (more or less regular) RE's ;-)

Comment: I tried using \pgfplotstable, but it would require adding all the missing & symbols in each row.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The result is obviously very poor, but I can't see any better way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\tameginormous}{m}
 {
  \croco_ginormous_tame:n { #1 }
 }

\tl_new:N \l__croco_ginormous_matrix_in_tl
\seq_new:N \l__croco_ginormous_matrix_out_seq
\seq_new:N \l__croco_ginormous_rows_seq
\seq_new:N \l__croco_ginormous_col_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \croco_ginormous_tame:n
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l__croco_ginormous_matrix_in_tl { #1 }
  % remove the beginning
  \regex_replace_once:nnN { \A .* \{c*\} } { } \l__croco_ginormous_matrix_in_tl
  % remove the end
  \regex_replace_once:nnN { \c{end} .* \Z } { } \l__croco_ginormous_matrix_in_tl
  % remove all \left and \right
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { \c{left}|\c{right} } { } \l__croco_ginormous_matrix_in_tl
  % split the input at \\
  \seq_set_split:NnV \l__croco_ginormous_rows_seq { \\ } \l__croco_ginormous_matrix_in_tl
  % now process the thing
  \seq_clear:N \l__croco_ginormous_matrix_out_seq
  \seq_map_indexed_function:NN \l__croco_ginormous_rows_seq \__croco_ginormous_row:nn
  % output
  \par
  \group_begin:
  \linespread{1.5}\selectfont
  \raggedright
  \setlength{\parindent}{-3em}\setlength{\leftskip}{3em}
  \seq_use:Nn \l__croco_ginormous_matrix_out_seq { \par }
  \par
  \group_end:
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__croco_ginormous_row:nn
 {% #1 = row index, #2 = row
  % split the row at &
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__croco_ginormous_col_seq { & } { #2 }
  \seq_map_indexed_inline:Nn \l__croco_ginormous_col_seq
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l__croco_ginormous_matrix_out_seq { $ r\sb{#1##1} = ##2 $ }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\tameginormous{
  \left(\begin{array}{ccccccc} 0 & c_{\theta_1} & s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_2} & c_{\theta_1}\,c_{\theta_3}-c_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_3} & s_{\theta_4}\,\left(c_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_3}+c_{\theta_2}\,c_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_1}\right)+c_{\theta_4}\,s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_2} & c_{\theta_5}\,\left(c_{\theta_1}\,c_{\theta_3}-c_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_3}\right)-s_{\theta_5}\,\left(c_{\theta_4}\,\left(c_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_3}+c_{\theta_2}\,c_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_1}\right)-s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_4}\right) & s_{\theta_6}\,\left(s_{\theta_5}\,\left(c_{\theta_1}\,c_{\theta_3}-c_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_3}\right)+c_{\theta_5}\,\left(c_{\theta_4}\,\left(c_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_3}+c_{\theta_2}\,c_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_1}\right)-s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_4}\right)\right)+c_{\theta_6}\,\left(s_{\theta_4}\,\left(c_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_3}+c_{\theta_2}\,c_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_1}\right)+c_{\theta_4}\,s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_2}\right)\\ 0 & s_{\theta_1} & -c_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_2} & c_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_1}+c_{\theta_1}\,c_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_3} & s_{\theta_4}\,\left(s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_3}-c_{\theta_1}\,c_{\theta_2}\,c_{\theta_3}\right)-c_{\theta_1}\,c_{\theta_4}\,s_{\theta_2} & c_{\theta_5}\,\left(c_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_1}+c_{\theta_1}\,c_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_3}\right)-s_{\theta_5}\,\left(c_{\theta_4}\,\left(s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_3}-c_{\theta_1}\,c_{\theta_2}\,c_{\theta_3}\right)+c_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_4}\right) & s_{\theta_6}\,\left(s_{\theta_5}\,\left(c_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_1}+c_{\theta_1}\,c_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_3}\right)+c_{\theta_5}\,\left(c_{\theta_4}\,\left(s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_3}-c_{\theta_1}\,c_{\theta_2}\,c_{\theta_3}\right)+c_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_4}\right)\right)+c_{\theta_6}\,\left(s_{\theta_4}\,\left(s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_3}-c_{\theta_1}\,c_{\theta_2}\,c_{\theta_3}\right)-c_{\theta_1}\,c_{\theta_4}\,s_{\theta_2}\right)\\ 1 & 0 & c_{\theta_2} & s_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_3} & c_{\theta_2}\,c_{\theta_4}-c_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_4} & s_{\theta_5}\,\left(c_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_4}+c_{\theta_3}\,c_{\theta_4}\,s_{\theta_2}\right)+c_{\theta_5}\,s_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_3} & c_{\theta_6}\,\left(c_{\theta_2}\,c_{\theta_4}-c_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_4}\right)-s_{\theta_6}\,\left(c_{\theta_5}\,\left(c_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_4}+c_{\theta_3}\,c_{\theta_4}\,s_{\theta_2}\right)-s_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_5}\right)\\ 0 & -\frac{17\,s_{\theta_1}}{50} & \frac{17\,c_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_2}}{50} & -\frac{2\,c_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_3}}{5}-\frac{17\,c_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_1}}{50}-\frac{17\,c_{\theta_1}\,c_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_3}}{50}-\frac{2\,c_{\theta_2}\,c_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_1}}{5} & \frac{17\,c_{\theta_1}\,c_{\theta_4}\,s_{\theta_2}}{50}+\frac{2\,c_{\theta_1}\,c_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_4}}{5}-\frac{17\,s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_4}}{50}+\frac{17\,c_{\theta_1}\,c_{\theta_2}\,c_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_4}}{50}-\frac{2\,c_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_4}}{5} & \left(c_{\theta_5}\,\left(c_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_1}+c_{\theta_1}\,c_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_3}\right)-s_{\theta_5}\,\left(c_{\theta_4}\,\left(s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_3}-c_{\theta_1}\,c_{\theta_2}\,c_{\theta_3}\right)+c_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_4}\right)\right)\,\left(\frac{17\,c_{\theta_2}}{50}+c_{\theta_2}\,\left(\frac{37\,c_{\theta_4}}{50}-\frac{37}{50}\right)-\frac{37\,c_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_4}}{50}-\frac{17}{50}\right)-\frac{57\,s_{\theta_5}\,\left(c_{\theta_1}\,c_{\theta_3}-c_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_3}\right)}{50}-\frac{57\,c_{\theta_5}\,\left(c_{\theta_4}\,\left(c_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_3}+c_{\theta_2}\,c_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_1}\right)-s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_4}\right)}{50}+\left(s_{\theta_5}\,\left(c_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_4}+c_{\theta_3}\,c_{\theta_4}\,s_{\theta_2}\right)+c_{\theta_5}\,s_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_3}\right)\,\left(\frac{17\,c_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_2}}{50}-\frac{37\,s_{\theta_4}\,\left(s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_3}-c_{\theta_1}\,c_{\theta_2}\,c_{\theta_3}\right)}{50}+c_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_2}\,\left(\frac{37\,c_{\theta_4}}{50}-\frac{37}{50}\right)\right) & \left(s_{\theta_6}\,\left(s_{\theta_5}\,\left(c_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_1}+c_{\theta_1}\,c_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_3}\right)+c_{\theta_5}\,\left(c_{\theta_4}\,\left(s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_3}-c_{\theta_1}\,c_{\theta_2}\,c_{\theta_3}\right)+c_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_4}\right)\right)+c_{\theta_6}\,\left(s_{\theta_4}\,\left(s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_3}-c_{\theta_1}\,c_{\theta_2}\,c_{\theta_3}\right)-c_{\theta_1}\,c_{\theta_4}\,s_{\theta_2}\right)\right)\,\left(\frac{17\,c_{\theta_2}}{50}+c_{\theta_2}\,\left(\frac{37\,c_{\theta_4}}{50}-\frac{37}{50}\right)-\frac{57\,s_{\theta_6}\,\left(c_{\theta_5}\,\left(c_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_4}+c_{\theta_3}\,c_{\theta_4}\,s_{\theta_2}\right)-s_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_5}\right)}{50}+\left(c_{\theta_2}\,c_{\theta_4}-c_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_4}\right)\,\left(\frac{57\,c_{\theta_6}}{50}-\frac{57}{50}\right)-\frac{37\,c_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_4}}{50}-\frac{17}{50}\right)-\left(c_{\theta_6}\,\left(c_{\theta_2}\,c_{\theta_4}-c_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_4}\right)-s_{\theta_6}\,\left(c_{\theta_5}\,\left(c_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_4}+c_{\theta_3}\,c_{\theta_4}\,s_{\theta_2}\right)-s_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_5}\right)\right)\,\left(\left(s_{\theta_4}\,\left(s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_3}-c_{\theta_1}\,c_{\theta_2}\,c_{\theta_3}\right)-c_{\theta_1}\,c_{\theta_4}\,s_{\theta_2}\right)\,\left(\frac{57\,c_{\theta_6}}{50}-\frac{57}{50}\right)+\frac{37\,s_{\theta_4}\,\left(s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_3}-c_{\theta_1}\,c_{\theta_2}\,c_{\theta_3}\right)}{50}+\frac{57\,s_{\theta_6}\,\left(s_{\theta_5}\,\left(c_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_1}+c_{\theta_1}\,c_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_3}\right)+c_{\theta_5}\,\left(c_{\theta_4}\,\left(s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_3}-c_{\theta_1}\,c_{\theta_2}\,c_{\theta_3}\right)+c_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_4}\right)\right)}{50}-\frac{17\,c_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_2}}{50}-c_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_2}\,\left(\frac{37\,c_{\theta_4}}{50}-\frac{37}{50}\right)\right)\\ 0 & \frac{17\,c_{\theta_1}}{50} & \frac{17\,s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_2}}{50} & \frac{17\,c_{\theta_1}\,c_{\theta_3}}{50}-\frac{2\,s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_3}}{5}+\frac{2\,c_{\theta_1}\,c_{\theta_2}\,c_{\theta_3}}{5}-\frac{17\,c_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_3}}{50} & \frac{17\,c_{\theta_4}\,s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_2}}{50}+\frac{17\,c_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_4}}{50}+\frac{2\,c_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_4}}{5}+\frac{2\,c_{\theta_1}\,c_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_4}}{5}+\frac{17\,c_{\theta_2}\,c_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_4}}{50} & \left(s_{\theta_5}\,\left(c_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_4}+c_{\theta_3}\,c_{\theta_4}\,s_{\theta_2}\right)+c_{\theta_5}\,s_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_3}\right)\,\left(\frac{17\,s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_2}}{50}+\frac{37\,s_{\theta_4}\,\left(c_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_3}+c_{\theta_2}\,c_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_1}\right)}{50}+s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_2}\,\left(\frac{37\,c_{\theta_4}}{50}-\frac{37}{50}\right)\right)-\frac{57\,s_{\theta_5}\,\left(c_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_1}+c_{\theta_1}\,c_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_3}\right)}{50}-\frac{57\,c_{\theta_5}\,\left(c_{\theta_4}\,\left(s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_3}-c_{\theta_1}\,c_{\theta_2}\,c_{\theta_3}\right)+c_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_4}\right)}{50}-\left(c_{\theta_5}\,\left(c_{\theta_1}\,c_{\theta_3}-c_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_3}\right)-s_{\theta_5}\,\left(c_{\theta_4}\,\left(c_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_3}+c_{\theta_2}\,c_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_1}\right)-s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_4}\right)\right)\,\left(\frac{17\,c_{\theta_2}}{50}+c_{\theta_2}\,\left(\frac{37\,c_{\theta_4}}{50}-\frac{37}{50}\right)-\frac{37\,c_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_4}}{50}-\frac{17}{50}\right) & \left(c_{\theta_6}\,\left(c_{\theta_2}\,c_{\theta_4}-c_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_4}\right)-s_{\theta_6}\,\left(c_{\theta_5}\,\left(c_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_4}+c_{\theta_3}\,c_{\theta_4}\,s_{\theta_2}\right)-s_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_5}\right)\right)\,\left(\frac{17\,s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_2}}{50}+\frac{37\,s_{\theta_4}\,\left(c_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_3}+c_{\theta_2}\,c_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_1}\right)}{50}+\left(s_{\theta_4}\,\left(c_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_3}+c_{\theta_2}\,c_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_1}\right)+c_{\theta_4}\,s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_2}\right)\,\left(\frac{57\,c_{\theta_6}}{50}-\frac{57}{50}\right)+\frac{57\,s_{\theta_6}\,\left(s_{\theta_5}\,\left(c_{\theta_1}\,c_{\theta_3}-c_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_3}\right)+c_{\theta_5}\,\left(c_{\theta_4}\,\left(c_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_3}+c_{\theta_2}\,c_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_1}\right)-s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_4}\right)\right)}{50}+s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_2}\,\left(\frac{37\,c_{\theta_4}}{50}-\frac{37}{50}\right)\right)-\left(s_{\theta_6}\,\left(s_{\theta_5}\,\left(c_{\theta_1}\,c_{\theta_3}-c_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_3}\right)+c_{\theta_5}\,\left(c_{\theta_4}\,\left(c_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_3}+c_{\theta_2}\,c_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_1}\right)-s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_4}\right)\right)+c_{\theta_6}\,\left(s_{\theta_4}\,\left(c_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_3}+c_{\theta_2}\,c_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_1}\right)+c_{\theta_4}\,s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_2}\right)\right)\,\left(\frac{17\,c_{\theta_2}}{50}+c_{\theta_2}\,\left(\frac{37\,c_{\theta_4}}{50}-\frac{37}{50}\right)-\frac{57\,s_{\theta_6}\,\left(c_{\theta_5}\,\left(c_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_4}+c_{\theta_3}\,c_{\theta_4}\,s_{\theta_2}\right)-s_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_5}\right)}{50}+\left(c_{\theta_2}\,c_{\theta_4}-c_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_4}\right)\,\left(\frac{57\,c_{\theta_6}}{50}-\frac{57}{50}\right)-\frac{37\,c_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_4}}{50}-\frac{17}{50}\right)\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{2\,c_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_2}}{5} & \frac{2\,s_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_4}}{5} & \frac{57\,c_{\theta_5}\,\left(c_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_4}+c_{\theta_3}\,c_{\theta_4}\,s_{\theta_2}\right)}{50}-\left(c_{\theta_5}\,\left(c_{\theta_1}\,c_{\theta_3}-c_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_3}\right)-s_{\theta_5}\,\left(c_{\theta_4}\,\left(c_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_3}+c_{\theta_2}\,c_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_1}\right)-s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_4}\right)\right)\,\left(\frac{17\,c_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_2}}{50}-\frac{37\,s_{\theta_4}\,\left(s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_3}-c_{\theta_1}\,c_{\theta_2}\,c_{\theta_3}\right)}{50}+c_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_2}\,\left(\frac{37\,c_{\theta_4}}{50}-\frac{37}{50}\right)\right)-\left(c_{\theta_5}\,\left(c_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_1}+c_{\theta_1}\,c_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_3}\right)-s_{\theta_5}\,\left(c_{\theta_4}\,\left(s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_3}-c_{\theta_1}\,c_{\theta_2}\,c_{\theta_3}\right)+c_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_4}\right)\right)\,\left(\frac{17\,s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_2}}{50}+\frac{37\,s_{\theta_4}\,\left(c_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_3}+c_{\theta_2}\,c_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_1}\right)}{50}+s_{\theta_1}\,s_{\theta_2}\,\left(\frac{37\,c_{\theta_4}}{50}-\frac{37}{50}\right)\right)-\frac{57\,s_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_5}}{50} & \frac{2\,c_{\theta_6}\,s_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_4}}{5}+\frac{2\,c_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_5}\,s_{\theta_6}}{5}+\frac{2\,c_{\theta_5}\,s_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_6}}{5}+\frac{2\,c_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_4}\,s_{\theta_5}\,s_{\theta_6}}{5}+\frac{2\,c_{\theta_3}\,c_{\theta_4}\,s_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_5}\,s_{\theta_6}}{5}+\frac{2\,c_{\theta_4}\,c_{\theta_5}\,s_{\theta_2}\,s_{\theta_3}\,s_{\theta_6}}{5} \end{array}\right)
}

\end{document}
```

#### Picture of the beginning

[image]

#### Picture of the ending

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. May I ask you why it doesn't go to the rest of elements?

Comment: @CroCo I cropped the picture, but I get two and a half pages full of complicated and unreadable formulas.

Comment: sorry never mind. Thank you so much. this is a hell of clever answer.

Comment: Why you're saying it is very poor?

Comment: @CroCo I added a picture with the final part: as a reader I don't want to see such a mess. `;-)`